# Coxeter groups and finitness of number of roots

Tags: gr.group-theory, coxeter-groups

Take any graph $\Gamma$ with $n$ vertices $\{v_1, v_2 \dots v_n\}$, and associate to this graph it's set of simple roots i.e. a vectors of the canonical basis $e_i, \ i=1..n$ of $R^n$ for each vertex $v_i$. Lets write $v_i \sim v_j$ if the two vertices are neighbours. Now consider the following set of $n$ linear transformations $\sigma_i: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, one for each vertex

$$e_i \mapsto -e_i + \sum\limits_{v_j \sim v_i} e_j \quad and \quad e_k \mapsto  e_k \text{ if } k \ne i$$

You realize that these $n$ transformations satisfies the following set of relations, call them alltogether $Rel_n$

(1) $\sigma_i^2 = 1 \ \forall i$

(2) $(\sigma_i\sigma_{j})^3 = 1 \text{ if } v_i \sim v_j  $

(3) $ (\sigma_i\sigma_j)^2= 1  \text{ if } v_i \not \sim v_j$

Let $\Gamma_n$ be the group with the following presentation $\Gamma_n  = \langle \sigma_i\dots \sigma_n \ | Rel_n \rangle$. Note that the above linear transformations give a linear representation of $\Gamma_n$. Now, let

$\Phi_0(\Gamma) := \{ w(e_i) \ | \ w \in \Gamma_n \}$

and then

$\Phi_{k+1}(\Gamma) := \{ w(x) \ | \ w \in \Gamma_n, x \in \Phi_{k}(G) \}$

$\bullet \quad$ What can we say about $\Phi(\Gamma):= \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} \Phi_k(\Gamma_n) $ ?

$\bullet \quad$ It is a known fact that $\Phi(\Gamma)$ is finite if and only if $\Gamma \in \{ A_m, D_m, E_6, E_7, E_8\}$ which are essentially the Dynkin diagrams of the finite Coxeter groups. I have managed a proof of this fact purely based on spectral properties of $\Gamma$.

$\bullet \quad$ The goal of my question is: can we imagine a proof purely based on Coxeter groups theory. Maybe all that is a trivial consequence of this theory...?

$\bullet \quad$ The "if" part of the assertion is probably the easiest part because in that case, $\Gamma_n$ is the Coxeter group associated to the Dynkin diagram $\Gamma$ and these Coxeter groups are finite and probably we have very precise information on how they act on the roots. But there is something to say...

$\bullet \quad$ The "only if" part is by far less obvious for me

$\bullet \quad$ Note that being finite in this case is equivalent to the fact that the norms $\| x \|$ are finite $\forall x \in \Phi(\Gamma)$. In a more general context, this equivalence is wrong and we have to drop the finitness of $\Phi(\Gamma)$ but we can keep the boundess criteria. This last context seems more linked with Hecke algebbras or (maybe) some kind of generalization of such algebras.

Comment: MMMh thanks for answer but can you elaborate a little bit. What track would you propose to chase such result

Comment: You may find such a proof in the book 'Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups' by James. E. Humphreys

Comment: Great  thanks Martin, I'll check that

Comment: Thanks for your time Sam. You are right, sorry for the bad explanations, I have rephrased all the post, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Now your question makes a lot more sense. This process seems very similar to "Kostant's game" (http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~bazse/reflection_groups.pdf#page=27) and some related ones (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152954/for-which-graphs-does-this-1-game-the-sponsor-game-terminate) but I'm not sure if it's exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the links Sam